# display a parent-child-child with django

Tags: django

I'm new to Django and get easily lost.

I have this app that have items. They are set as a list with parent-child relations.

Later I want to display tasks attached to items. But for now. I can't even figure out how to display the parent-childs.

This is my simplt model

```
class Item(models.Model):
  item_title = models.Charfield()
  item_parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

I want to display them as:

```
Item 1
- item 2
- item 3
-- item 4
-- item 5
Item 6
- item 7
-- item 8
--- item 9
```

I have tried with making a view that take Item.objects.all().order_by('item_parent')

And the template with a FOR - IN. But I don't know how to seperate to show first parent then child, and another child is that exist.

I just manage to list everthing in order by the item_parent. Which is not the same.

Appreciate some expert help to a beginner like me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use :

```
item_parent__self_set
```

Its mean for each item_parent you have the childs list (_set if for query_set)
When you define a ForeignKey, you automatically get a reverse relation.

You can do something more simple :

```
class Item(models.Model):
    item_title = models.Charfield()
    item_parent = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children')
```

And you retrieve :

```
for item in Item.objects.filter(item_parent__isnull=True):
    print item.item_title
    for child in item.children.all():
        print child.item_title
```

Comment: `Item.objects.all()` should be `Item.objects.filter(item_parent__isnull=True)` to filter out children nodes from the root directory. This won't generate a tree of parent-children-children like in the question example output.

Comment: Thank you. Made progress. Only thing is that all rows in Item is showing twice, except the ones that have children. Children are shown under parent as well as top level without a child. Is the best practice to use IF ITEM_PARENT IS NOT NULL in the FOR-IN?

Comment: Sorry but @Vlad V saw this and posted while I was writing. Fixed it with the filter. Thanks both of you!

Comment: Yep, i will upgrade my exemple :)

Comment: I just noticed that this only show one level below First parent. If I have a Item that have another Child as parent, it will not show. I'm currently looking into this. Also the warning from Vlad about this recursively quering the db. Looking for a better solution.

Answer (score 5):

If performance is not an issue then a solution based on MaximeK's answer is the simplest. The performance is not great as you are recursively querying the database. For a very small amount of items this is OK.

A more efficient way that also can support an indefinite depth of children is to fetch all the items at once and then create a tree that you can then traverse to print the items in order. It is more code to write but it might be educational if not directly helpful with your problem.

First step: we generate a [tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_(data_structure)) for each item that does not have a root (stored in roots). Side note: We can think of these trees as one big tree starting at a single root node that has all the items with no parents as children, but for simplicity we don't do that.

```
references = {}
roots = []

items = Item.objects.all()

for item in items:

    # get or make a new node
    if item.pk in references:
        n = references[item.pk]
        n.item = item
    else:
        n = Node(children=[], item=item)
        references[item.pk] = n

    if item.item_parent is None:
        # if item is root (no parent)
        roots.append(n)
    else:
        # if item has a parent
        if item.item_parent_id in references:
            # item parent already seen
            parent_n = references[item.item_parent_id]
        else:
            # item not seen yet
            parent_n = Node(children=[], item=None)
        parent_n.children.append(n)
```

Second step: we traverse the tree depth-first

```
def dfs(root, level=0):
    print("-"*level, root.item.item_title)
    for node in root.children:
        dfs(node, level+1)

for root in roots:
    dfs(root)
```

This is just printing the `item_title` with `-` in front to denote the indentation level. I generated some random items and the output looks like this:

```
python mouse cat
- mouse monitor car
-- blue car cat
green machine computer
- monitor green yellow
yellow pen blue
- mouse cat yellow
yellow blue green
- cat monitor python
-- blue yellow python
-- machine green cat
--- monitor blue python
-- machine computer mouse
-- machine car blue
car pen yellow
```

I don't know how to do this in Django templates, but we can generate HTML that looks like this:

```html
<ul>
    <li>pen monitor cat
        <ul>
            <li>computer mouse machine</li>
            <li>yellow python car
                <ul>
                    <li>monitor python pen</li>
                    <li>mouse blue green</li>
                    <li>python blue cat</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>mouse computer cat</li>
    <li>computer python car
        <ul>
            <li>pen green python
                <ul>
                    <li>mouse computer machine</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>machine yellow mouse</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>yellow python monitor</li>
    <li>car cat pen
        <ul>
            <li>pen machine blue
                <ul>
                    <li>mouse computer machine</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Depth-first traversal that generates the above HTML. I wrote it as a class to avoid global variables.

```
class TreeHtmlRender:
    def __init__(self, roots):
        self.roots = roots

    def traverse(self):
        self.html_result  = "<ul>"
        for root in self.roots:
            self.dfs(root, 0)
        self.html_result += "</ul>"
        return self.html_result

    def dfs(self, root, level=0):
        self.html_result += ("<li>%s" % root.item.item_title)
        if len(root.children) > 0:
            self.html_result += "<ul>"
            for node in root.children:
                self.dfs(node, level+1)
            self.html_result += "</ul>"
        self.html_result += "</li>"


r = TreeHtmlRender(roots)
print(r.traverse())
```

To render on a webpage you can simply send the HTML to your template via a context and use the safe flag (`{{ items_tree | html }}`). You can pack all I said in this answer into a neat template tag that will render trees if you need or want to.

Note: A clear limitation of this approach is that it will not function properly if not all items are selected. If you select a subset of all your items and if it happens that you select child nodes and omit their parents, the child nodes will never be displayed.

Comment: You're doing a `Item.objects.all()` and after that you iterate that. Isn't that going to execute a query for every item?

Comment: @Daan I think it does a single query to fetch all items at once, like a `SELECT * FROM items;`